# Не могу нормально раскодировать строку не могу убрать спец символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, base64

Помогите раскодировать корректно 0JjQu9GM0Y8g0JDQvdCw0YHRjNC10LI=

```
$femail = base64_decode($femail);
```

не могу убрать спецсимволы.

```
   пробовал так  `$femail=  preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $femail);`
```

наоборот текс удаляет а символы остаются.

в итоге такой вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В этой строке нет никаких спецсимволов.

Comment: Странно )) где то еще ошибка скин приложил как на странице  это выглядит , вот и что только не пробовал эти символы на месте

Comment: Ну мы не знаем что и как вы выводите на странице…

Comment: на странице UTF-8

Comment: вот так возвращает base64_decode($from_email, true);   null  , значит символы есть все таки

Comment: значит вы показываете нам не то что лежит в переменной `$from_email`

Comment: в переменной 0JjQu9GM0Y8g0JDQvdCw0YHRjNC10LI= оно и лежит

Comment: Нет. Вы ошибаетесь. https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/?s=s7EvyCjg5VJJK8rPjU_NTczMUbBVUDLwygostXT3NYi0SDfwcgksS3EuN4j0CMryczY08PG0VbIGaYEpT0osTjUziU9JTc5PSdVAMkpHoaSoNFUTqDg1OSNfAdkSPQWlmDwlhAxYFMgFAA%2C%2C&v=8.1.4

Comment: так спасибо теперь ясно ) очень помогли

Comment: наверно js еще на странице сейчас буду искать что меняет код

Comment: разобрался  решает проблему

Comment: function imap_utf8_fix($string) {
            return iconv_mime_decode($string,0,"UTF-8");
          }

Answer (score 0):

base64 строка, что вы предоставили, корректна и не содержит спец символов)

> 0JjQu9GM0Y8g0JDQvdCw0YHRjNC10LI=
> Результат = Илья Анасьев
> Обратное кодирование дает туже строку 0JjQu9GM0Y8g0JDQvdCw0YHRjNC10LI=

Предполагаю, у вас что-то не так с кодировками.

Comment: На странице  все нормально      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                                                       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                                                       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: если вывожу без base64 все нормально текст  0JjQu9GM0Y8g0JDQvdCw0YHRjNC10LI=  кстати если поставить base64_decode($from_email, true);  то все по 0;

Comment: это строка имени в почте

Answer (score 0):

Так как это с imap почты то данный код решает проблему

```
    $femail =  $inbox->from_email; 
       
       function imap_utf8_fix($string) {
        return iconv_mime_decode($string,0,"UTF-8");
      }

      echo (imap_utf8_fix($femail));
```